# Why am I getting this invalid syntax error?

Tags: python, django

```
   from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
  File "/Users/Scott/Desktop/myvirtualenv/crazy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 152
    


context['related_url'] = mark_safe(related_url)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error and was hoping someone could let me know what I need to do here?

```
def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
    context = super(ForeignKeyRawIdWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
    rel_to = self.rel.model
    if rel_to in self.admin_site._registry:
        # The related object is registered with the same AdminSite
        related_url = reverse(
            'admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (
                rel_to._meta.app_label,
                rel_to._meta.model_name,
            ),
            current_app=self.admin_site.name,
        )

        params = self.url_parameters()
        if params:
            related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join(
                ('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items())
        context['related_url'] = mark_safe(related_url)
        context['link_title'] = _('Lookup')
        # The JavaScript code looks for this class.
        context['widget']['attrs'].setdefault('class', 'vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField')
    if context['widget']['value']:
        context['link_label'], context['link_url'] = self.label_and_url_for_value(value)
    return context
```

Here is the full line of code from where the syntax error is occurring.  Again I am not sure why I am getting this error.  From what I can tell it doesn't have anything to do with the code I've written in Atom but is part of the actual line of coding in the widgets.py file for Django.

Comment: Would you mind providing some more of the code? it may be something before this, like the assignment of "content" or a bracket that wasn't closed.

Comment: def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super(ForeignKeyRawIdWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        rel_to = self.rel.model
        if rel_to in self.admin_site._registry:
            # The related object is registered with the same AdminSite
            related_url = reverse(
                'admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (
                    rel_to._meta.app_label,
                    rel_to._meta.model_name,
                ),
                current_app=self.admin_site.name,
            )

Comment: params = self.url_parameters()
            if params:
                related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join(
                    ('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items())
            context['related_url'] = mark_safe(related_url)
            context['link_title'] = _('Lookup')
            # The JavaScript code looks for this class.
            context['widget']['attrs'].setdefault('class', 'vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField')
        if context['widget']['value']:
            context['link_label'], context['link_url'] = self.label_and_url_for_value(value)
        return context

Comment: Here is what I believe is the entire line of code in this section of widgets.py.  I hope this helps with being able to diagnose this issue.

Comment: Could you add these as edits to the original question and format them as code?

Comment: As always, it's an unclosed parenthesis on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a closing parenthesis in the line above the SyntaxError.

```
def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
    context = super(ForeignKeyRawIdWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
    rel_to = self.rel.model
    if rel_to in self.admin_site._registry:
        # The related object is registered with the same AdminSite
        related_url = reverse(
            'admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (
                rel_to._meta.app_label,
                rel_to._meta.model_name,
            ),
            current_app=self.admin_site.name,
        )

        params = self.url_parameters()
        if params:
            related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join(
                ('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()))  # Added a )
        context['related_url'] = mark_safe(related_url)
        context['link_title'] = _('Lookup')
        # The JavaScript code looks for this class.
        context['widget']['attrs'].setdefault('class', 'vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField')
    if context['widget']['value']:
        context['link_label'], context['link_url'] = self.label_and_url_for_value(value)
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you, that resolved this issue.  Now back to my original import issue with social_django.utils.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Great, please select this as the answer if it answered your question.